# How do I get the value of the sequential number of 2 pieces foreach function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, nested-loops, html2pdf

i have a problem with my code, because i use a nested foreach to get some value from my database.
i need to get the value of the sequential number in my table.

I use this code :

```
    $TipeIklan          = $this->input->post('inputTipeIklan');
    $ProdukCode     = $this->input->post('inputPtodukCode');
    $Date               = $this->input->post('inputDate');
    $WherCustomer       = array("CustomerCode >="       => $Customer1,
                            "CustomerCode <="       => $Customer2);
    $ArrCustomer        = $this->customer_m->order_by("CustomerCode","ASC")->get_many_by($WherCustomer);

    if($ArrCustomer){
        foreach($ArrCustomer as $item_customer){
            $Kwitansi   = $this->kwitansi_m->getUmurPiutang($item_customer->CustomerCode,$ProdukCode,$Date);
            if($Kwitansi){
                $content .='
                            <tr>
                                <td class="fontB" colspan="17">'.$item_customer->CustomerCode.'</td>
                            </tr>';

                foreach($Kwitansi as $item){
                    $n  = count($Kwitansi);
                    $no = $n;
                    $content .='
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="font" width="200">'.$no.'</td>
                                </tr>';
                    $n++;           
                } ### end of foreach $Kwitansi as $item ###
            } ### end of $Kwitansi ###
        } ### end of foreach $ArrCustomer as $item_customer ###
    } ### end of $ArrCustomer ###
```

But I get a number like this,
look at the left side of the document
[RESULT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KrEQG-byp5GTSQHsj9_lwB2eCMq6xdpB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you want sequence by invoince number?

Comment: @KamleshSolanki no, i just want start number from 1 , 2, 3 . . . . , in my case, i got sequence number but its always start from 1 if CustomerCode is different

Comment: Pleae read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code

```
foreach($Kwitansi as $item){
        $n  = count($Kwitansi);
        $no = $n;
        $content .='
                            <tr>
                                <td class="font" width="200">'.$no.'</td>
                            </tr>';
        $n++;
```

}

to

```
$m  = 0;
foreach($Kwitansi as $item){
        $n = $m+1;
        $content .='
                            <tr>
                                <td class="font" width="200">'.$no.'</td>
                            </tr>';
        $n++;
        $m++;
    }

 $n  = count($Kwitansi); this wrong because of if you got 5 count then start with 5,6,7...n. So, you need to put before loop and assign $n=1 to start with 1,2 .... so on
```

Comment: its still same
 i add something like this
    $m = 0;
    $n= $m + 1;

and before end of foreach invoice i add ,
    $n++;
    $m++;
and its work

thank for answer my question

Comment: why you need to add more variable like $m

Comment: because it using two foreach, just like old time
how to create number like this ?
1
12
123
1234
12345

its using two variables

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want but do you want to display the numbers sequentially for the items?

Say,
Customer X 
1) item A 
Customer Y 
2) item B 
3) item C 
Customer Z 
4) item D

If so :
Then initialize your counter before the $ArrCustomer foreach and increment it inside the $Kwitansi foreach.

```
$TipeIklan          = $this->input->post('inputTipeIklan');
    $ProdukCode     = $this->input->post('inputPtodukCode');
    $Date               = $this->input->post('inputDate');
    $WherCustomer       = array("CustomerCode >="       => $Customer1,
                            "CustomerCode <="       => $Customer2);
    $ArrCustomer        = $this->customer_m->order_by("CustomerCode","ASC")->get_many_by($WherCustomer);
    $n = 1; // counter that never gets reset.

    if($ArrCustomer){
        foreach($ArrCustomer as $item_customer){
            $Kwitansi   = $this->kwitansi_m->getUmurPiutang($item_customer->CustomerCode,$ProdukCode,$Date);
            if($Kwitansi){
                $content .='
                            <tr>
                                <td class="fontB" colspan="17">'.$item_customer->CustomerCode.'</td>
                            </tr>';

                foreach($Kwitansi as $item){
                    $no = $n;
                    $content .='
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="font" width="200">'.$no.'</td>
                                </tr>';
                    $n++;           
                } ### end of foreach $Kwitansi as $item ###
            } ### end of $Kwitansi ###
        } ### end of foreach $ArrCustomer as $item_customer ###
    } ### end of $ArrCustomer ###
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: this is what i wany,
 i just need numbering item from invoice table, Where the customercode is available in invoice table,

look my comment before with @Kamlesh Solanki

Comment: i solve this problem by my self, but thanks for give me a comment